# Why is 10000000000000000 != 10000000000000000?

Tags: c++, c

To begin with, take a look at the following code in Visual Studio using C++:

```
float a = 10000000000000000.0;
float b = a - 10000000000000000.0;
```

When printing them out, it turns out:

```
a = 10000000272564224.000000
b = 272564224.000000
```

And when viewing them in Watch under Debug, it turns out:

```
-Name-   -Value-          -Type-
a        1.0000000e+016   float
b        2.7256422e+008   float
```

---

**Pre-question**: I am sure that **10000000000000000.0** is within the range of `float`. Why is that we cannot get correct **a**/ **b** using `float`?

---

**Followup-question**:
For pre-question, based on all great following answers. I know that the reason is that a **32-bit float** has an accuracy of about 7 digits, so beyond the first 6-7 digits, all bets are off. That's why the math doesn't work out, and printing looks wrong for these large numbers. I have to use double for more accuracy. So **why float claims to be able to handle large numbers and at the same time we cannot trust it?**

Comment: This is not a well posed question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Revised the question. Thanks.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Fixed. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The huge number you are using is indeed within the "range" of float, but not all its digits are within the "accuracy" of float.  A 32-bit float has an accuracy of about 7 digits, so beyond the first 6-7 digits, all bets are off.  That's why the math doesn't work out, and printing looks "wrong" when you use these large numbers.  If you want more accuracy, use double.  For more, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers

Comment: I see, thanks. Then why **float** claims to be able to handle large numbers and at the same time we cannot trust it?

Comment: That's a very good question.  For a lot of applications, floating-point math is simply not good enough.  For example, handling currency (money).  For such applications, you might consider a Decimal or Big Integer class depending on your needs.  An example is GMP, the GNU Multi Precision library, but there are lots of others.  The regular float and double work the way they do simply because they are small types which are intrinsically supported by most processors with high speed.  They're not very precise, and they never will be.

Answer (score 2):

A float number takes about 6-7 decimal places (23 bit for the fraction) so any number with more decimal places is just an approximation. Which leads to that rondom number.

For more about floating point format precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

**For the updated question:** 
You should never use floating point format when the precision is required. We can't just specify larger space of memory. Handling numbers with very large amount of decimal places needs a very large amount of memory .So more complicated methods are used instead ( for exemple using a string format then processing the characters successively) .

To avoid that problem use `double` which gives about 16-17 decimal places (52 bit for the fraction) or `long double` for even more precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double a = 10000000000000000.0;
double b = a - 10000000000000000.0;
printf("%f\n%f", a, b);
}
```

exemple http://ideone.com/rJN1QI

Comment: So any value longer than 6 decimal places is out of control for **float**? It seems not right here.

Comment: How many decimal places can **double** or **long double** handle?

Comment: if he's using VS/VC++, `long double` is equivalent to `double`.

Comment: double gives 52 bits for the fraction which means 16 decimal places

Comment: @rullof Maybe the question should be why **float** claims to be able to handle large numbers and at the same time we cannot trust it?

Comment: `float` can handle large numbers; it just can't handle them very precisely.

Comment: @herohuyongtao For exemple if you want to handle a numbre of 100 decimal place precision you will need a very large amount of memory to handle the fractional part (do some math)

Comment: @herohuyongtao Updated for the new question

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is caused by implicit conversions and lack of accuracy of `float`.

Let me fill in the implicit conversions for you:

```
float a = (float)10000000000000000.0;
float b = (float)((double)a - 10000000000000000.0);
```

This converts the literal `double` to `float`, and the closest it can get is 10000000272564224. And then the subtraction is performed using `double`, not `float`, so the second 10000000000000000.0 does not lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `nextafter` function to get a better idea of the precision of floating-point types. `nextafter` takes two arguments; it returns the *adjacent* representable number to its first argument, in the direction of its second argument.

The value `10000000000000000.0` (or `1.0e16`) is well within the *range* of representable values of type `float`, but that value itself cannot be represented exactly.

Here's a small program that illustrates the issue:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a    =       10000000000000000.0;
    double d_a =       10000000000000000.0;

    printf("      %20.2f\n", nextafterf(a, 0.0f));
    printf("a   = %20.2f\n", a);
    printf("      %20.2f\n", nextafterf(a, 1.0e30f));
    putchar('\n');

    printf("      %20.2f\n", nextafter(d_a, 0.0));
    printf("d_a = %20.2f\n", d_a);
    printf("      %20.2f\n", nextafter(d_a, 1.0e30));
    putchar('\n');
}
```

and here's its output on my system:

```
       9999999198822400.00
a   = 10000000272564224.00
      10000001346306048.00

       9999999999999998.00
d_a = 10000000000000000.00
      10000000000000002.00
```

If you use type `float`, the closest you can get to `10000000000000000.00` is `10000000272564224.00`.

But in your second declaration:

```
float b = a - 10000000000000000.0
```

the subtraction is done in type `double`; the constant `10000000000000000.0` is already of type double, and `a` is promoted to `double` to match. So this takes the poor approximation of `1.0e16` that's stored in `a`, and subtracts from it the much better approximation (in fact it's exact) that can be represented in type `double`.